# Combine output of multiple lists into one list (Python)

Tags: python, list

I'm trying to create an output of one list. I think I can join multiple lists together but as it's stored in one place I'm struggling.

```
    my_list = (len(largest) // len(STR[words]))
        print (my_list)
```

Output:

```
    ['DAVID', 4]
    ['MATTHEW', 1]
    ['PETER', 5]
```

I need it to look like this:

```
    ['DAVID', 4, 'MATTHEW', 1, 'PETER',5]
```

Comment: Please create a [mcve]. `(len(largest) // len(STR[words]))` should create an `int`, not a list.

Comment: Yes, I changed it into a list later. 
`STRnumber = (len(largest) // len(STR[words]))` 
`MAXnumberTuple = (STR[words], STRnumber)`
`#convert tuple to list`
`my_list = list(MAXnumberTuple)`

Comment: Sorry, I'm new here, struggling to format my answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `zip()` function build into python

```
l1 = ['DAVID', 4]
l2 = ['MATTHEW', 1]
l3 = ['PETER', 5]

x = zip(l1,l2, l3)
print(list(x))
```

It will give you this output:

```
[('DAVID', 'MATTHEW', 'PETER'), (4, 1, 5)]
```

**EDIT:**
If you get the lists as a list of lists, then you can do it like this, and it makes it scalable, it will produce the same output.

```
lists = [
        ['DAVID', 4],
        ['MATTHEW', 1],
        ['PETER', 5],
        ]

x = zip(*lists)
print(list(x))
```

**EDIT AGAIN**
if you want a dictionary then you can do like this:

```
liste = [
        ['DAVID', 4],
        ['MATTHEW', 1],
        ['PETER', 5],
        ]

dicta ={}
for i in range(len(liste)):
    dicta[liste[i][0]]=liste[i][1] 

print(dicta)
```

and it will produce this output:

```
{
  "DAVID": 4,
  "MATTHEW": 1,
  "PETER": 5
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately, depending on the input the number of lists can change so I don't think this would help in my situation. I may have to look at earlier code and arrange a better output.

Comment: Do you get the lists as a list of lists?

Comment: I'm iterating through a text and the output creates one list per iteration.

Comment: ok so you can just append them to a big list at do what is in the end of my answer. But have you concidered getting a dictionary instead? :)

Comment: I believe a list is sufficient for what I need. I'll lookup append and see what I can find.

Comment: Just create an empty list above your loop and then when you get your output in the loop write `list.append(output[0])` and `list.append(output[1])`

Answer (score 0):

You can add lists in Python, this isn't efficient but simply doing:

```
list1 + list2
```

will work for you.

So something like this:

```
new_list = []

for l in your_lists:
    new_list += l

print(new_list)
```

Comment: Would I need to get access to each list that is stored in my_list above before doing that?